# "NOTICE: identifier will be truncated" in psql when I try "ALTER SYSTEM SET"

Tags: postgresql, psql

PostgreSQL 12.9
When I try to run:

```
psql -c'alter system set archive_command="pg_probackup-12 archive-push -B /pg_probackup --instance=pgsql-n1 --wal-file-path=%p --wal-file-name=%f --remote-host=pg-backup1 --remote-user=postgres --compress";'
```

I get a notice:

```
NOTICE:  identifier "pg_probackup-12 archive-push -B /pg_probackup --instance=pgsql-n1 --wal-file-path=%p --wal-file-name=%f --remote-host=pg-backup1 --remote-user=postgres --compress" will be truncated to "pg_probackup-12 archive-push -B /pg_probackup --instance=pgsql-"
```

```
show archive_command; 

                         archive_command
-----------------------------------------------------------------
 pg_probackup-12 archive-push -B /pg_probackup --instance=pgsql-
```

But if i manual edit postgresql.conf(or postgresql.auto.conf) then all fine.

```
archive_command
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 pg_probackup-12 archive-push -B /pg_probackup --instance=pgsql-n1 --wal-file-path=%p --wal-file-name=%f --remote-host=pg-backup1 --remote-user=postgres --compress
```

But I should be able to set the "archive_command" parameter with "alter system set".

Why is the parameter value in this case have a identifier length limit?

How can I fix this without changing NAMEDATALEN?

Comment: Whatever is enclosed in double quotes in SQL is an identifier, but it has to be a string constant. String constants must be surrounded by single quotes or dollar quotes (like `$$`).

Answer (score 1):

The correct command line, after properly quoting the command string constant (literal), as Laurenz Albe suggested in a comment):

```shell
psql -c "alter system set archive_command="\
"'pg_probackup-12 archive-push -B /pg_probackup --instance=pgsql-n1 "\
"--wal-file-path=%p --wal-file-name=%f --remote-host=pg-backup1 "\
"--remote-user=postgres --compress';"
```

(Command is wrapped for readability.)

The [upper limit of identifier length](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/limits.html) is 63 bytes and can be increased by recompiling PostgreSQL.

[Literals (string constants)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS).